# image is not shown in pdf with laravel-snappy

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf, laravel-snappy

I use barryvdh/laravel-snappy to generate pdf. But when I add an img it does not show.

Here's my code:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('xx.jpeg') }}" style="height: 50px; width:100px">
```

but the area of image is blank(gray rectangle)

[image]

if I use this:

```html
<img src="xx.jpeg" style="height: 50px; width:100px">
```

got this error:

[image]

Comment: can you access the image using url?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this

```
$pdf = SnappyPdf::setOptions([
        'encoding' => 'utf-8',
        'enable-local-file-access' => true
    ])->loadView('report', compact('data'));
```

And in a blade file

```
<img alt="" src="{{ public_path().'/images/img.png' }}" height="75px" width="270px"/>
```

I used these options for the image to load, I hope it helps